# Atom Editor gcc linker -lm in centos 7

Tags: atom-editor

I knew in the latest Linux, there is no direct linkage to math.h for c math library. so, to make it work there is requirement to add linker flag -lm . for example $ gcc count.c -lm
But in Atom Editor I am using "gpp-compiler 3.0.7" and in the settings > C Compiler there is "gcc" compiler and it works fine without "math.h" library related operations. How to and where to put
-lm linking flag to make gcc avail to link "math.h" library ?

Note: " settings > C Compiler > Default: gcc -lm" doesn't work.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: If you are using "gpp" why do you change the setting for "gcc"? Isn't there a setting for "gpp"?

Comment: Thank you for your response sir, gpp-compiler uses gcc as C Compiler by default in its core settings. But as I mentioned gcc cannot deal with math.h library directly in current linux versions and nedd to give linker flag  for math.h  it's  m  so - in command  line it should be like  $ gcc hello.c -lm.  so my question is how  and where can I explicitly put  this  " -lm".

Comment: Or  any recommendation to solve the issue ?

Comment: Since I don't use Atom I have to guess: There may be some setting for "additional libraries". I'd try to enter "m" there and then look at the command line which is used by Atom. At least other IDEs work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in gpp-cmpiler settings in "C Compiler options" , simply add -lm.

same for the c++ compiler Options too.

For C

Settings > C Compiler Options > (write) -lm

for C++

Settings > C++ Compiler Options > (write) -lm